# Which Of The Following Is An Inner Product?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, inner-products

> Let $C[-1,2]$ be the space of all continuous functions $f:[-1,2]\to \mathbb{C}$.
>
> Which of the following define an inner product on $C[-1,2]$ and which do not?
>
> $$\langle f,g\rangle =\int_{-1}^{2}|f(t)+g(t)|dt$$

a. $$\langle f,f\rangle =\int_{-1}^{2}|f(t)+f(t)|dt=2\int_{-1}^{2}|f(t)|dt$$
b.
$$\overline{\langle g,f\rangle }= \overline{\int_{-1}^{2}|g(t)+f(t)|dt} = \int_{-1}^{2}\overline{|g(t)+f(t)|}dt = \int_{-1}^{2}\overline{|f(t)+g(t)|}dt=\langle f,g\rangle $$
c.
$$\langle \alpha f+\beta g,h\rangle=\int_{-1}^{2}|\alpha f(t) +\beta g(t)+h(t)|dt\neq\alpha \int_{-1}^{2}|f(t)+h(t)|dt+\beta \int_{-1}^{2}|g(t)+h(t)|dt=\alpha\langle f,h\rangle+\beta\langle g,h\rangle$$

Can we be sure that the expression in a. is $\geq 0$? as the function can be decreasing? so the overall expression will be less than $0$

Can we move the conjugate inside the integral as in b.?

Comment: The property (a), if I correctly guessed what it is, actually is true. The absolute values imply that $|f(t)|\ge0$ for all $t$. To prove that  $\langle f,f\rangle=0$ only when $f=0$ you need continuity. But that is all moot, because, as you predict, (c) fails. As a teacher I would be happier if you gave a numerical example involving fixed $\alpha,\beta,f,g,h$. After all, those integrals could accidentally always be equal in spite of appearances to the contrary. I think you can use $\alpha=\beta=f=g=h=1$ to find a numerical counterexample, but please check :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: That's a nice commentary. It seems to me that you are a good teacher.

Comment: In general can we say that an integral of a function in absolute value will be always greater or equal to zero? For the real it seems to hold (as the area under the graph)

Comment: gbox, for a continuous function we can say that. If its absolute value is $\epsilon>0$ at some point $x$, it is $>\epsilon/2$ in an interval of non-zero length around $x$, and therefore $\int_{-1}^2|f|>0$. Otherwise we have examples like a function that takes value $1$ at a single point and is zero elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not an inner product. For instance, take $f(x)=g(x)=x$ and $\alpha=-1$. Then$$\langle\alpha f,g\rangle=\int_{-1}^2|-x+x|\,\mathrm dx=0$$
and$$\alpha\langle f,g\rangle=-\int_{-1}^2|2x|\,\mathrm dx\neq0.$$So, in general it is not true that $\langle\alpha f,g\rangle=\alpha\langle f,g\rangle$.